# Python rowcount socket.gethostbyname

Tags: python, sockets, dns

Okay so I have to grab DNS records from our database and well it works except for the ptr records. I found that they sometimes put a hostname so I thought this would help:

```
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    dns = row[2]
    wip = row[6]
    ptr = socket.gethostbyname(row[6])
```

Which for some reason does not work, and I have to write the output to our dns server' s config. I have also tried doing

```
 ptr= socket.gethostbyname(wip)"
```

and

```
row[6] = socket.gethostbyname(row[6])
```

which also does not work.

The error I keep getting is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dns.py", line 40, in <module>
    row[6] = socket.gethostbyname(row[6])
socket.gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
```

Thanks for your attention

Sincerely yours,

Jordy

Comment: can you supply some example values for `row[2]`, `row[6]` ?

Comment: local-data: "example. IN A ns1.example."

Comment: what is that supposed to be?

Comment: It' s supposed to output the DNS records from the database to the DNS configuration file. so in this case row[2] is example and row[6] is ns1.example.

Comment: It' s supposed to get the ip adress of each hostname in the rows. (Used for reverse DNS)

Comment: well obviously there is no record with `ns1.example` so that `gethostbyname` can not work. you need to find the record for `ns1.example` in your db and put that into dns

Comment: It is there, it works but it has some conflicts with the reverse DNS records because some times it puts a hostname instead of an IP which is why I want to grab the IP from the hostname.

Comment: well clearly the record you want is NOT IN DNS. you probably need to get it from the database and put it into DNS

Comment: Would you have any tips/solution for that?